# A Tool to manage lots of documents/notes?

Tags: note-taking, document-management, document-indexing

I have a lot of notes in the form of:

- txt
- docx
- markdown format file

I am looking for a tool that can:

- quick search through file names
- quick search through file contents
- support doc editing with markdown syntax
- run on Windows
- preferably free.
- preferably a one-stop solution.

Currently I am using Everywhere + AgentRansack. But with so many small files, the content search is slowing down. And I have to use other software for editing.

Comment: How many users collaborate on these documents? Just you?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Just me. It's kind of a personal knowledge base.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Tagspaces. it's main purpose is to tag folders and documents for easier searching, plus it provides inbuilt markdown document creation. here is the site: [tagspaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Notepad++ ([Download](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.html)) "Find in Files" application?

It's free, and I find it really fast especially since you can restrict the following parameters for a search:

```
Filters
Directory
Follow current doc
Subfolders
HiddenFolders
```

Plus Regular Exressions & Quick Extended items!

Comment: @smwikipedia Have you had a chance to try Notepad++ yet?